# Scala DataFrame: Explode an array

Tags: scala, dataframe, explode, apache-spark-sql

I am using the spark libraries in Scala. I have created a DataFrame using

```
val searchArr = Array(
  StructField("log",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("user", StructType(Array(
    StructField("date",StringType,true),
    StructField("ua",StringType,true),
    StructField("ui",LongType,true))),true),
  StructField("what",StructType(Array(
    StructField("q1",ArrayType(IntegerType, true),true),
    StructField("q2",ArrayType(IntegerType, true),true),
    StructField("sid",StringType,true),
    StructField("url",StringType,true))),true),
  StructField("where",StructType(Array(
    StructField("o1",IntegerType,true),
    StructField("o2",IntegerType,true))),true)
)

val searchSt = new StructType(searchArr)    

val searchData = sqlContext.jsonFile(searchPath, searchSt)
```

I am now what to explode the field what.q1, which should contain an array of integers, but the documentation is limited:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#explode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20scala.Function1,%20scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag)

So far I tried a few things without much luck

```
val searchSplit = searchData.explode("q1", "rb")(q1 => q1.getList[Int](0).toArray())
```

Any ideas/examples of how to use explode on an array?

Comment: The documentation you're looking at is 1.4.0.  Is that the version of spark you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with an UDF on field *"what"*? Something like that could be useful:

```
val explode = udf {
(aStr: GenericRowWithSchema) => 
  aStr match {
      case null => ""
      case _  =>  aStr.getList(0).get(0).toString()
  }
}


val newDF = df.withColumn("newColumn", explode(col("what")))
```

where:

- **getList(0)** returns "q1" field
- **get(0)** returns the first element of "q1"

I'm not sure but you could try to use **getAs[T](fieldName: String)** instead of **getList(index: Int)**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Scala; but in Python/pyspark, the array type column nested within a struct type field can be exploded as follows. If it works for you, then you can convert it to corresponding Scala representation.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType, LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType

schema = StructType([
  StructField("log", IntegerType()),
  StructField("user", StructType([
    StructField("date", StringType()),
    StructField("ua", StringType()),
    StructField("ui", LongType())])),
  StructField("what", StructType([
    StructField("q1", ArrayType(IntegerType())),
    StructField("q2", ArrayType(IntegerType())),
    StructField("sid", StringType()),
    StructField("url", StringType())])),
  StructField("where", StructType([
    StructField("o1", IntegerType()),
    StructField("o2", IntegerType())]))
])

data = [((1), ("2022-01-01","ua",1), ([1,2,3],[6],"sid","url"), (7,8))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+--------------------------+------+
|log|user               |what                      |where |
+---+-------------------+--------------------------+------+
|1  |{2022-01-01, ua, 1}|{[1, 2, 3], [6], sid, url}|{7, 8}|
+---+-------------------+--------------------------+------+
```

With **what.q1** exploded:

```py
df.withColumn("what.q1_exploded", explode(col("what.q1"))).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+--------------------------+------+----------------+
|log|user               |what                      |where |what.q1_exploded|
+---+-------------------+--------------------------+------+----------------+
|1  |{2022-01-01, ua, 1}|{[1, 2, 3], [6], sid, url}|{7, 8}|1               |
|1  |{2022-01-01, ua, 1}|{[1, 2, 3], [6], sid, url}|{7, 8}|2               |
|1  |{2022-01-01, ua, 1}|{[1, 2, 3], [6], sid, url}|{7, 8}|3               |
+---+-------------------+--------------------------+------+----------------+
```